# How to push values into array using recursive function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

I'm trying to push values into array by recursive function, but I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Array.push() is not a function", although the push() method is a regular array method. Where the problem could be?

```
let someArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let someNum = 3;

let fillArr = (arr, num) => x = (num != 0) ? fillArr(arr.push(num), num -1) : arr;

console.log(fillArr(someArr, someNum))

// expected output: ['a', 'b', 'c', 3, 2, 1];
// actual output: Uncaught TypeError: arr.push is not a function
```

Comment: Use `concat` instead of `push`

Comment: `Array.push` returns an int, and you're passing that int as argument for `arr` in your recursive call.

Answer (score 3):

The comma operator is often overlooked; it could provide a nice escape hatch:

```js
const fillArr =
  (arr, num) =>
    (num === 0
      ? arr
      : fillArr((arr.push(num), arr), num - 1));
//..............^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

fillArr(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3)
//=> ["a", "b", "c", 3, 2, 1]
```

However you shouldn't work on the original array with `Array#push` as it will mutate it (unless it was your intention!)

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
fillArr(arr, 3);
arr;
//=> ["a", "b", "c", 3, 2, 1] Oops!
```

Instead you should work with a new array:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const fillArr =
  (arr, num, nums = []) =>
    (num === 0
      ? arr.concat(nums)
      : fillArr(arr, num - 1, (nums.push(num), nums)));

fillArr(arr, 3);
//=> ["a", "b", "c", 3, 2, 1]
arr;
//=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 1):

What Mr.@deceze said is correct. If you still want to do that..
Do something like

```
let fillArr = (arr, num) => x = (num != 0) ? fillArr(arr, num -1, arr.push(num)) : arr;
```

fillArr  will receive someArr got  num pushed and the last argument will be ignored